# Json transformation : always map element to an array

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have a backend which can return response like this if i have only one element :

```
{
  "object": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  }
}
```

but also like this, if I have many elements :

```
{
  "object": [
    {
      "a": "1",
      "b": "2"
    },
    {
      "a": "3",
      "b": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to always have an array for my "object" even if I only have one item inside, like this :

```
{
  "object": [
    {
      "a": "1",
      "b": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

How is it possible which JOLT transformation ? I tried some tricks, without result

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cardinality" operation does exactly this.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "object": "MANY"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Indeed... Thank you !